# Implementing frameBuffers in Camera2API

Tags: java, android

How to get the Image frames direct way from Camera using camera2API or getting it from Surface or Texture, please help me in doing that by providing samples for the above

Thanks in Advance Looking for the help.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: i have edited my question please help me now

Answer (score 0):

You can use imageReader to do that,Once you have implemented the image reader.
Then You can get the image output in Byte Buffer form.

```
   private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener
            = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Image image = reader.acquireNextImage();
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            try {
                rotation = getRotationCompensation(mCameraId);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onImageAvailable: CameraAccessException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mTextRecognizer.imageFromByteBuffer(byteBuffer, rotation);

            image.close();
        }
    };
```

Am creating a text recognizer which uses mlkit text recognition.
The 'byteBuffer' is the image output.